# Lenovo T430i Cannot go to bios setup

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

My Laptop is T430i with Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit. I can boot my laptop smoothly but I cannot go to bios setup. When my laptop restart I press **Enter** key on my keyboard to interrupt the startup then, it will tell press **F1** to enter bios setup but when I press **F1** it will be blank screen forever, I have to just power off and start that it.

I tried lot of thing like

1. I try to restart my laptop in advance mode to boot in uefi setting but uefi setting option is missing
2. Then I found that my windows setup is in **legacy mode**, may be that is the reason
3. I use mbr2gpt tool under windows/system32 but it always crash.

I don't loose my data and enable virtualization in my bios. How can I do it.

Comment: If it's in legacy mode, have you tried just pressing `F12` just as the laptop powers on?  i.e. press F12 a few times just after pressing the power button.

Comment: Pressing F12 will bring me to boot menu not bios setup

Comment: I meant F1.  Answer provided below.

Comment: Please read my updated question

Comment: Apologies, my F1 answer deleted.

Answer (score 0):

An option is, if you're willing to open the laptop and take a small risk, is to hard reset the bios by unplugging the coin cell battery (when the laptop is fully powered off and the main battery is removed).

The coin cell battery is a round yellow battery, attached to the motherboard by a small white plug.  On the T430, I think it's easy to get to.  Either, next to the RAM, or under the keyboard, so maybe not a big job to find it.

Once, removed and plugged back in, reassemble and power on the laptop.  Then try F1 again.

Comment: Please my updated question

Comment: @Milind I understand, the laptop blank screens when trying to enter Bios setup.  I've updated my answer to suggest trying a hard reset (your choice if you want to try this).

Comment: It is risky. I can't do it as it is my company laptop

Comment: @Milind It's not massively risky, but don't do it if you're not comfortable tearing the laptop down.  Then sorry, not sure if I have a better answer, hope someone else can jump in and help.  Maybe tell us what you want to do in the Bios, is it just to enable CPU virtualization support?

Comment: Yes  I want enable virtualization support

Comment: Also want to see that my motherboard supports UEFI or not